# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with android 4.2

Tags: android

Here i am using this code load Json. It is work fine with android 2.2 but when i am using android 4.2 it throws **android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**   exception please give me solution

```
 public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;

static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

           if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
              Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                  "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
              return null;
           }

           HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

        //HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = getResponseEntity.getContent();            

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("IO", e.getMessage().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

}

i am also using google api.

Comment: Question has been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150637/networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12615724/1168654

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Write below code into your MainActivity file after setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

And below import statement into your java file.

```
import android.os.StrictMode;
```

Comment: it is not the correct way to turn off StrictMode. The correct way is to call network operations in AsyncTask instead of turning off

Comment: As @SankarV says it should be done using an AsyncTask instead of turning off strictmode.

Comment: This is not recommended. AsyncTask is a better way  to do this.

Comment: so many bunches of solutions recommended but none of them solved the problem except this one.

Answer (score 13):

This is the correct way:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask <String, Void, String>{

    static InputStream is = null;

static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
           final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

           if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) { 
              Log.w(getClass().getSimpleName(), 
                  "Error " + statusCode + " for URL " + url); 
              return null;
           }

           HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

        //HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        //HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = getResponseEntity.getContent();            

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("IO", e.getMessage().toString());
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;


}
protected void onPostExecute(String page)
{   
    //onPostExecute
}   
}
```

To call it (from main):

```
mJSONParser = new JSONParser();
mJSONParser.execute();
```

Comment: did you even test that? Does not work what's that url? return obj is not accessible its outside the loop

Answer (score 6):

Please make sure that you don't do any network access on UI Thread, instead  do it in  [Async Task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

The reason why your application crashes on Android versions 3.0 and above, but works fine on Android 2.x is because  since HoneyComb are much stricter about abuse against the UI Thread. For example, when an Android device running HoneyComb or above detects a network access on the UI thread, a NetworkOnMainThreadException will be thrown.

See [this](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/06/app-force-close-honeycomb-ics.html)

Comment: instead of HoneyComb and Ice Cream Sandwich I will say Since HoneyComb. In fact JB has the same policy

Answer (score 1):

`android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` occurs when you try to access network on your main thread (You main activity execution). To avoid this, you must create a separate thread or `AsyncTask` or `Runnable` implementation to execute your JSON data loading. Since HoneyComb you can not further execute the network task on main thread. 
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception) is the implementation using `AsyncTask` for a network task execution

Answer (score 1):

Use StrictMode Something like this:-

```
   if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        }
```

Comment: it is not the correct way to turn off StrictMode. The correct way is to call network operations in AsyncTask instead of turning off. is they provided the check just for turning off?

Comment: we can use asynkTask also but for me its working

Comment: ya it will work but not the best way. they have provided the check to ensure developer calls the network operations in separate thread not for simply turning off.

Comment: ohh! thanx asyncTask is good