# How to fix Exception: Failure deliviring result ResultInfo

Tags: android, android-activity, runtimeexception

I have an application that displays a dialog with a listview. After the user chooses an option from the listview, I will change a record using the information that the user selects.
For this I thought about using the command `setResult (RESULT_OK, intent);` but my code is generating the following exception:

```
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.sisteplantbrasil/.WorkOrderInfo (has extras) }} to activity {com.sisteplantbrasil/com.sisteplantbrasil.WorkOrderInfo}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3182)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3225)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:140)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1275)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:144)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:76)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:76)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:146)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.sisteplantbrasil.webservices.PrismaWebServices.getDateTimeNow(PrismaWebServices.java:144)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.sisteplantbrasil.entities.LaborRecord.getCurrentDate(LaborRecord.java:120)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.sisteplantbrasil.entities.LaborRecord.getLaborEndDate(LaborRecord.java:146)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.sisteplantbrasil.queries.sql.LaborRecordDBQueries.insertLaborRecord(LaborRecordDBQueries.java:35)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.sisteplantbrasil.entities.LaborRecord.offlineSave(LaborRecord.java:167)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at com.sisteplantbrasil.WorkOrderInfo.onActivityResult(WorkOrderInfo.java:492)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5390)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3178)
09-25 12:01:06.035: E/AndroidRuntime(8783):     ... 11 more
```

My code:

```
public void onClickEndLabor(View v) {
    if (selectedNextWorkOrderState != null) {
        Intent intent;

        if (showNotes) {
            EditText txtNotes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtNotes);
            intent = IntentFactory.createWorkOrderInfo(
                    WorkOrderStateWorkflow.this,
                    selectedNextWorkOrderState, txtNotes.getText()
                            .toString(), Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        } else {
            intent = IntentFactory.createWorkOrderInfo(
                    WorkOrderStateWorkflow.this,
                    selectedNextWorkOrderState, "",
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        }

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

        finish();
    }
}
```

WorkOrderInfo Activity:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent intent) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            WorkOrderState nextWOState = (WorkOrderState) extras
                    .getSerializable("workOrderState");

            nextState = nextWOState.getWorkOrderState();
            String notes = extras.getString("notes");
            WorkOrder workOrder = Application.getInstance().getWorkOrder();

            previousWOState = new WorkOrderState(
                    workOrder.getWorkOrderState(),
                    workOrder.getWorkOrderStateName());

            if (Application.getInstance().useLaborRecord()) {
                lre.setWorkOrder(workOrder);
                lre.setNotes(notes);

                progress = ProgressDialog.show(this, getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.Wait), getResources()
                        .getString(R.string.EndingLabor));

                if (Application.getInstance().getStatus() == AppStatus.ONLINE) {
                    lre.asyncSave(endHandler);
                    lre.getWorkOrder().offlineSave(false);
                    lre.offlineSave(false, false);
                } else {
                    if (lre.offlineSave(true, false)
                            && lre.getWorkOrder().offlineSave(false)) {
                        endHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                    } else {
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.obj = new QueryException(getResources()
                                .getString(R.string.ErrorSaving));

                        endHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                    }
                }
            } else {

                ChangeWOState changeState = new ChangeWOState(
                        WorkOrderInfo.this);
                changeState.execute();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with the code?
Thank´s for your attention!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkOnMainThreadException: The exception that is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2009/05/painless-threading.html

here is link that illustrates how to use asynctask

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

http://blog.vogella.com/2012/02/22/android-strictmode-networkonmainthreadexception/

Comment: I know using AsyncTask, but I wonder WHERE I use it. I do not see where using an asynchronous method.

Comment: @user1792343 Refer the links.. and use your codes inside doinbackground process...