# Android App Crashing While Retrieving XML File

Tags: android

I am developing a simple android app which will fetch and display a xml data in textview. The following is the code.

```
try {
            t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            URL url = new URL("http://www.sevenzaseo.com/androidapi.php");
            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(conn.getInputStream());

            NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("socialinfo");
            for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);
                NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("facebooklikes");
                Element line = (Element) title.item(0);
                t1.setText(line.getTextContent());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And The XML File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xml>
<socialinfo>
    <facebooklikes>420</facebooklikes>
    <twitterfollowers>12</twitterfollowers>
    <googleplusfollowers>121</googleplusfollowers>
    <linkedinfollowers>24</linkedinfollowers>
    <websiteviews>500</websiteviews>
</socialinfo>
</xml>
```

But the apps is not working and it is not fetching the URL data. I am targeting it on my Samsung Galaxy S3 with 3G Connection.Can anybody please help?

Comment: Post your logcat error message

Comment: Hey Nabin, as i am a newbie i dont know how to post my logcat error message. Can you please help.

Comment: And to copy the error in log cat, you can select the required lines and right click to get filter message and copy paste here.

Comment: I think you are getting android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException exception

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2

Answer (score 0):

You are using network on UI thread, remove it and use Async Task

Comment: But How can I use async task?

Comment: Search net for something like this: connecting to server by async task android ... there are a lot of libraries for example volley is very good

Answer (score 0):

You **can't make network processing in your Main Thread**. So you need to use **AsyncTask**. Retrieve the data in doInBackground() and finally display it in **textview** or other in **postExecute()**
**Try using AsyncTask** as follows:

```
public class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject> {

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {


        try {


            }
        } catch () {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject url) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread for some case. you may remove this as well
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //do something at last, may be display result to textview or use adapter
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You may want to look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14250989/how-to-use-asynctask-correctly-android)

Comment: Yes but in some case it needs. For example applying a huge set of data and getting view from other class

Answer (score 0):

You can't make network processing in your Main Thread(UI Thread) Android never let you to do so you should to use Async Task by creating a new thread in order to do this.

Read this:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

**Use this code inplace of your code it will solve your problem**

```
static final String URL = "http://www.sevenzaseo.com/androidapi.php";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_TASK = "socialinfo"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_FACEBOOKLIKE = "facebooklikes";
    static final String KEY_TWITTERFOLL = "twitterfollowers";
    static final String KEY_GOODLEPLUS = "googleplusfollowers";
    static final String KEY_LINKEDIN = "linkedinfollowers";
    static final String KEY_WESITEVIEW = "websiteviews";


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
            String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
            Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

            NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_TASK);
            // looping through all task nodes <task>
            for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(KEY_FACEBOOKLIKE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_FACEBOOKLIKE));
                map.put(KEY_TWITTERFOLL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TWITTERFOLL));
                map.put(KEY_GOODLEPLUS,parser.getValue(e, KEY_GOODLEPLUS));
                map.put(KEY_LINKEDIN,"Linkined: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINKEDIN));
                map.put(KEY_WESITEVIEW,"WebsiteCount: " + parser.getValue(e, KEY_WESITEVIEW));

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                menuItems.add(map);
            }
```

**Create this class in your package folder**

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }

    /**
     * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
     * @param url string
     * */
    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String xml = null;

        try {
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return xml;
    }

    /**
     * Getting XML DOM element
     * @param XML string
     * */
    public Document getDomElement(String xml){
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
                doc = db.parse(is); 

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }

            return doc;
    }

    /** Getting node value
      * @param elem element
      */
     public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
         Node child;
         if( elem != null){
             if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
                 for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                     if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                         return child.getNodeValue();
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
         return "";
     }

     /**
      * Getting node value
      * @param Element node
      * @param key string
      * */
     public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
            NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
            return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
        }
}
```

Comment: XMLParser cannot be resolved of a type. How to fix this error.

Comment: @Nitesh Yadav press ctrl shift o, hey you must be more patient to learn android.

Comment: @Nitesh Yadav brother before starting to code you must have to learn some basic concepts of android app development until and unless we can't help you dear sorry :-(