# Posting data through service crashes the application

Tags: android, post, service, crash

I'm trying to post data to web server through a background service.

The function `PostData` sends the data to the server, but when I added it the program shows:

> unfortunately the program stopped working

Here's my code:

```
package com.yahya.trackingsysem;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyService extends Service {

    Handler handler=new Handler();
    String info;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
hello();
    }

    void hello(){

        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Starting service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           ////////////////////
                postData();
           ////////////////////
                handler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(r, 10000);

    }   

    //********************* فنكشن الارسال
    public void postData() {
        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.webserver.net/tracker.php");

        try {
            // Add your data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", "Hi"));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
          httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    } 
    //****************************************



    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

And the stack trace:

```
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.yahya.trackingsysem.MyService.postData(MyService.java:60)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.yahya.trackingsysem.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:37)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-27 06:11:59.094: E/AndroidRuntime(810):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-27 06:12:09.094: I/Process(810): Sending signal. PID: 810 SIG: 9
10-27 06:12:24.545: D/AndroidRuntime(828): Shutting down VM
10-27 06:12:24.545: W/dalvikvm(828): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41465700)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.yahya.trackingsysem.MyService.postData(MyService.java:60)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.yahya.trackingsysem.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:37)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-27 06:12:24.595: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cann't use any UI related stuff in thread and here you are showing Toast message in a thread that why it crashing. For this you have to use handler for showing toast message.

Example ..

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();                   
                bundle.putString("myKey", dateString);
                msg.setData(bundle);
                handler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
      };

private final Handler handler = new Handler() {

      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

          String aResponse = msg.getData().getString("message");

          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

          }
};
```

//Write this code on your service class.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
}
```

//Mainfest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: i don't need toast so i deleted it bu the problem still the same

Comment: Hi ...Added two lines of code on my above post check this. I hope it will work.

Comment: @tektoktek And also check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2

Comment: it's not crashing anymore this small code fixed the issue and i don't know how,but thanks now i can go to see the next steps to see why the server not receiving the string

Answer (score 3):

The problem might be with the Toast.

Remove the TOAST.show().

Comment: the toast was working fine till i added the function PostDate() though i tried removing toast but same problem rised

Comment: you can see the logacat now