# Trying to get text from the text file located on sever

Tags: android, networkonmainthread, android-strictmode

I am trying to get strings from the text file from server and show it on `ListView`. I am calling `getTextListFromUrl()` from pull to refresh, by overriding the method `onRefersh()`. But I am stuck somewhere. Here is my code

```
public class ScreenTwoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private static final String CLASS_TAG = ScreenTwoActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private ListView mLvData;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen_2);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_referesh_layout);
        mLvData = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv_screen_2);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        getRefreshContent();
    }

    /**
     * On swipe refresh new data will being fetched from list
     */
    private void getRefreshContent() {

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ScreenTwoActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getTextListFromUrl());
                mLvData.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    private List<String> getTextListFromUrl() {

        List<String> listTextData = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            URL textUrl = new URL("http://thehealthybillion.com/assignment/q3.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));
            String stringBuffer;
            while ((stringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i(CLASS_TAG, stringBuffer);
                listTextData.add(stringBuffer);
            }
            bufferReader.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return  listTextData;
    }
}
```

This is the error I am getting on log

```
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1145)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.Dns$1.getAllByName(Dns.java:28)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:216)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:122)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:292)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:345)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:179)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at com.thb.vidyanand.assignmentthb.ScreenTwoActivity.getTextListFromUrl(ScreenTwoActivity.java:86)
            at com.thb.vidyanand.assignmentthb.ScreenTwoActivity.access$100(ScreenTwoActivity.java:22)
            at com.thb.vidyanand.assignmentthb.ScreenTwoActivity$1.run(ScreenTwoActivity.java:66)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:633)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Can anyone tell me what is going wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing network related task on your main thread (UI thread) so it's throwing `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Move all the heavy network related work to a worker thread by using `AyncTask` or `Handler`.

Even after using `Handler` if you're still getting the exception, add the below code in your Activity's `onCreate()`.

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
}
```

Source: [Error StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22395417/3701433)

Refer: [StrictMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html) for more info.

Comment: But I am giving call to this method getTextListFromUrl() from the handler only. You can check the code.

Comment: I see it now, let me see what's the problem then.

Comment: Which device (OS version ) you're using to run this application?

Comment: Android Version 4.4.2

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22395546/3701433 I think this answer might help you. Let me know so that I can edit this answer and make it relevant.

Answer (score 0):

When you are connecting to internet you need use AsyncTask and call it from doInBackground method.

Your error can be solve use `StrictMode.enableDefaults()` in your onCreate, but use this only for debug.

Answer (score 0):

Use async task to fetch the data from the server, Dont do network related stuffs in main thread.
Please refer this links:

[How to fix android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

[android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException with android 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2)

Comment: But I am calling the method from the handler.