# Android UDP Client

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, udp, udpclient

So I made a simple UDP Client for android, and for some reason it doesn't want to work. I've been struggling with this for like 5 hours now, and I can't find the problem. I even looked almost all the tutorials on the internet, to compare the codes, but I had no luck.

```java
String serverString = "192.168.1.109";
int port = 7777;

Log.d("adam", "Debug");

DatagramSocket socket = null ;

String msg = "Hello World!";

try {
    socket = new DatagramSocket() ;

    InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(serverString);
    byte [] data = msg.getBytes() ;
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, host, port );
    Log.d("adam", "Debug2");

    socket.send(packet) ;

    Log.d("adam", "Packet sent" );
} catch( Exception e )
{
    Log.d("adam", "Exception");
    Log.e("adam", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
}
finally
{
    if( socket != null ) {
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

My mainfest:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here is the debug img:

[image: logcat image]

As you can see the "Packet sent" text is not in the logcat. So the problem is probably with the `send()` function. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: network on main thread is not allowed by default. there is special function to change that behavior. you can disable that strict mode by `StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy =  new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`

Comment: Well, I know now. Just found a thread with networking issue on android. And they had the same solution there :D I tested it and worked fine. (Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2) Is this the easiest method to solve this issue? Thanks for the help btw. :) Sorry for opening this thread, but i was busy solving this issue all day, and I tought I never gonna find out what's the problem.

Comment: Best to avoid doing any I/O on the Android main (UI) thread for a production application. A blocking socket call will cause poor application responsiveness.  Use an AsyncTask or a dedicated thread to implement your client protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never ever run networking on the main thread. Do not do the work around that Mark suggests.

When you send data you should use an ASyncTAsk or a Thread.

Here is a very simple threaded function:

```
Thread sendDate = new Thread() {
@Override
public void run() {
    String serverString = "192.168.1.109";
    int port = 7777;

    Log.d("adam", "Debug");

    DatagramSocket socket = null ;

    String msg = "Hello World!";

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket() ;

        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName(serverString);
        byte [] data = msg.getBytes() ;
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( data, data.length, host, port );
        Log.d("adam", "Debug2");

        socket.send(packet) ;

        Log.d("adam", "Packet sent" );
    } catch( Exception e )
    {
        Log.d("adam", "Exception");
        Log.e("adam", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
    }
    finally
    {
        if( socket != null ) {
            socket.close();
        }
    }
    }
};
sendDate.start();
```

If you want to tell the user if the data was sent then you should use an ASyncTask