# how to stop asynctask when internet is connected but no internet access in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

```
String url = "http://xyzcloud.com/xyz/xyz.php";
```

this the url am trying to get the data from cloud,if internet is connected then async task will execute
i wrote this method for checking wether internet is connected or not, here in my mobile wifi is connetecd when am trying to execute it is giving exception

```
public boolean checkOnlineState()
    {
        boolean val = false;
        ConnectivityManager CManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo NInfo = CManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (NInfo != null && NInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            try {
                if (InetAddress.getByName(url).isReachable(10000))
                {
                    // host reachable
                    val=true;
                    Log.e("checkOnlineState", "" + val);
                }
                else
                {
                    // host not reachable
                    val = false;
                    Log.e("checkOnlineState", "" + val);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return val;
    }
```

Comment: this is the exception am getting 

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.xyz.xyz, PID: 13405
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException                                       
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1288)
 at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:432)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:253)
 at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:306)

Comment: handle socket timeout and connection time out in the catch block

Comment: after adding two exceptions it returns false

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2

Comment: how about putting val = false; to catch block ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;

public class ConnectionDetector {

    private Context context;

    public ConnectionDetector(Context context) {

        this.context = context;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Service.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if ( connectivity != null) {

            NetworkInfo info = connectivity.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            if (info != null) {

                if (info.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then for example, you can make use of it:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(this);

        if (cd.isConnected()) {
            // do something
        } else {
            //do something
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

I use this approach in my apps (which requires Internet connection) and didn't face any problem yet.

Comment: wife is connected but no INTERNET access in this case it is giving  this exception  org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://xyzcloud.com refused

Comment: Have you added permision to your Manifest file: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />