# android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException in AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, exception, networking, android-asynctask

I'm using Async task for downloading a pdf file from web API but somehow it is giving exception in doInbackground() method for read(buffer).
first time read() reads 1735 bytes but on second call it gives exception doesn't understand why???
Here is the code`enter code here`

```
public ImportPdfAsyncTask(Context c)
{
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    Call<ResponseBody> call = downloadService.downloadFileWithDynamicUrlSync();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d("my", "Server contacted and has file");

                boolean writtenToDisk = writeResponseBodyToDisk(response.body());;

                Log.d("my", "File written to disk?" + writtenToDisk);
            } else {
                Log.d("my", "Server contact failed");
            }

        }
```

And here is the method

```
private boolean writeResponseBodyToDisk(ResponseBody body) 
{

    try{
        File file = new File(mContext.getExternalCacheDir()+File.separator+"myPDF");
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        OutputStream outputStream = null;

        try {
            byte[] fileReader = new byte[6000];
            long fileSize = body.contentLength();
            long fileSizeDownloaded = 0;

            inputStream = body.byteStream();

            outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            while (true)
            {

                Log.d("my","# of times");
                int read = inputStream.read(fileReader); 
                //Here getting Ex when called second time
                Log.d("my","bytes read"+read);
                if(read == -1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                outputStream.write(fileReader,0,read);
                fileSizeDownloaded += read;

                Log.d("my","File downloaded "+fileSizeDownloaded+" of"+
                fileSize);

            }

            outputStream.flush();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("my","in ex");
            Log.d("my",e.getMessage()+123);
            Log.d("my",e.toString());
            return false;
        }
        finally {
            if(inputStream != null)
                inputStream.close();
            if(outputStream != null)
                outputStream.close();
        }
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Calling Async task as:

```
ImportPdfAsyncTask task = new ImportPdfAsyncTask(getApplicationContext());
    task.execute();
```

Comment: your error log?

Comment: Post your `onPreExecute()` block.

Comment: I think Here is no need of Async Task...

Comment: here is the flow of tags:
 D/my: Server contacted and has file
D/my: # of times
D/my: bytes read1753
D/my: File downloaded 1753 of4752
D/my: # of times
D/my: in ex
D/my: null123
D/my: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
D/my: File written to disk?false

Comment: @DevendraSingh I dont have onPreEx function

Comment: but here is the constructor:

    public ImportPdfAsyncTask(Context c)
    {
        mContext = c;
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439587/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception-with-android-4-2

Comment: Please post your whole `AsyncTack` and its invocation.Check this http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2013/05/android-http-downlod-upload-multipart.html

Comment: you will get result onPostExecute() method, but you are done in doInBackground(), Please change result  on onPostExecute() method.

Comment: Solved :

I was using retrofit2 and using Streating annotation with my function so I remove the streaming annotation and problem solved